# Random Page not found error on asp.net application in IE6

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-6

Lately we are receiving complaints from users about Page not Found errors on production environment. This happens during Login page load or default page load in the asp.net application.

The application on the production environment did throw the Page not Found error. But when we tried to access the same application  from test environment it worked without any problem.

I have read about client-side handling for form submission which results in a race condition with the form being submitted twice.  IE 6 turns out to be especially vulnerable to this problem because of how it handles multiple connections to the same hostname.

I am unable to figure out what could be the issue because the application runs fine on other machines and only specific machines give this problem.

Comment: did you look at the logs? we can't really help without more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the button after the first click, therefore blocking multiple clicks. Also have you tried replicating on production? Perhaps it is environment specific.

Answer (score 0):

It was some machine configuration. The infrastructure team could not quite figure out what the issue was, but they formatted the machines which resolved the issues for the user. Not the best of solutions.
Logs did not indicate any detail.